# Raid Drive Upgrades

Tags: raid, raid5

I have a RAID 5 setup with 5 2TB drives.  If I start to replace the 2TB with 4TB, once I have enough, can the Array be moved to 4TB's?  I know that if I put a 4TB in a 2TB Raid, the 4TB will recognize 2TB for the RAID.

Comment: What kind of (software/hardware) RAID controller are you using?

Comment: Also note that upgrading a RAID **5** from 8 to 16 TB creates an entirely new set of problems: 1. Rebuilding a 16 TB array will take a significant amount of time, during which the remaining drives will be stressed and more prone to fail. With RAID 5, a second failure will kill your entire array. 2. Desktop-grade drives are only guaranteed to have less than 1 uncorrectable bit error every 12.5 TB, so there's a good chance you'll encounter an uncorrectable error that (depending on your RAID solution) might kill your array as well. Consider carefully if you might want to switch to RAID 6 instead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your RAID controller is. With software RAID on Linux - pretty much anything is possible. Quoting from `man mdadm`:

> ```
>    Grow   Grow (or shrink) an array, or otherwise reshape it in some way.
>           Currently supported growth options including changing the active 
>           size of component devices and changing the number  of  active
>           devices  in Linear and RAID levels 0/1/4/5/6, changing the RAID
>           level between 0, 1, 5, and 6, and between 0 and 10, changing the
>           chunk size and layout for RAID 0,4,5,6,10 as well as adding or
>           removing a write-intent bitmap.
> ```

Hardware RAID controllers often supported limited array modifications. You will have to consult the documentation for your model if you are using one.

Answer (score 0):

A generic way to expand any raid array;

- Update all disk like you already do. (one big one)
- Create a backup.
- Be sure the backup is good.
- Now do a clone of the array/volume. Like an offline clone with a bootable acronis for server or symantec system recovery.
- Erase/delete the raid array.
- Recreate the raid array bigger with the new disk.
- Reapply the clone, like acronis it even offer to resize the partition for you.